# Angular instantiate module error

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

Please help to identify, what is wrong in below angular Hello World! first program.

```html
<html>
 <head>
  <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="Scripts/angular.js" />
  <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="Scripts/angular-resource.js" />
  <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="Scripts/angular-route.js" />
  <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="Scripts/angular-cookies.js" />
  <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="Scripts/angular-sanitize.js" />
      
  <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
   function Student($scope){
    $scope.Name= 'Akshay';
    $scope.City= 'Mumbai';    
   };
   
   var app = angular.module("myApp");
   app.controller("Student", Student)
  </script>
 </head>
 <body ng-app="myApp">
  <form>
  <div id="dvStudent" ng-controller="Student">
   Name: <input type="text" name="txtStudentName" id="txtStudentName" ng-model="Name" />
   City: <input type="text" name="txtStudentCity" id="txtStudentCity" ng-model="City" />
   <input type="button" name="btnSave" id="btnStudentSave" value="Save" />&nbsp;<input type="reset" name="btnReset" id="btnStudentReset" value="Reset" />
   <br />   
   You have inputed Name: {{Name}} & City: {{City}}
  </div>
  </form>
 </body>
</html>
```

This is the error I am getting

```
angular.js:68 Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module myApp due to:
Error: [$injector:nomod] Module 'myApp' is not available! You either misspelled the module name or forgot to load it. If registering a module ensure that you specify the dependencies as the second argument.
http://errors.angularjs.org/1.5.7/$injector/nomod?p0=myApp
```

Answer (score 0):

You haven't provided us the full error, but most likely the problem is that you're missing the second parameter to `angular.module()`:

```
var app = angular.module("myApp", []);
```

Also FYI, you should not use self-closing tags for `<script>` elements. You should explicitly include a closing tag. Also, the `language` attribute is deprecated and the `type` attribute is not needed when the script is JavaScript:

```
<script src="Scripts/angular.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

As you not provided full error i noticed your mistakes and provide you step for initializing `Angular`

**STEP 1** make `index.html`

```
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="lib/angular.js" />
        <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="js/app.js" />

    </head>
    <body ng-app="myApp">
        <form>
        <div id="dvStudent" ng-controller="Student">
            <label>Name:</label> <input type="text" name="txtStudentName" id="txtStudentName" ng-model="Name" />
            <label>City:</label> <input type="text" name="txtStudentCity" id="txtStudentCity" ng-model="City" />
            <input type="button" name="btnSave" id="btnStudentSave" value="Save" />
            <input type="reset" name="btnReset" id="btnStudentReset" value="Reset" />
            <br />          
            <p>You have inputed Name: {{Name}} & City: {{City}} </p>
        </div>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

**STEP 2** Make two folders `lib`  and `js`  place angular file in lib and `app.js` in js folder

**app.js**

```
var app = angular.module("myApp",[]);
            app.controller("Student", funtion($scope){
                $scope.Name= 'Akshay';
                $scope.City: 'Mumbai';          
            });
```

Comment: I am so sorry for posting the error text, my post is now edited with error text.